# zsh for-loop iterating file extension multiple times resulting in File/Path Error: No Such File

Tags: file, for-loop, zsh, macos-monterey

I've been using a bash for-loop for a bioinformatics project without problem until a few days ago, then it suddenly stopped working. I'm on OSX V12.1.

Command:

```
for FILE in `ls *.fasta` 
do
F=$(basename "$FILE".fasta) COMMAND -f "$F".input -o "$F".output 
done
```

It's a very simple for-loop, but starting three days ago, it started iterating over the file extension and giving this error:

> File/Path Error: No such file: 'FILE.fasta.fasta'

I'm not sure what the issue is. I've tried unsetting both F and FILE, but that hasn't worked. I've done the old 'turn everything off and back on', which also didn't work. I've done my best to scour the internet for a solution, but I may be missing the correct terminology because I've come up empty.

The bioinformatics software I am using is Anvi'o, but I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Please don't use the `bash` tag for `zsh` questions. They're not the same, and `bash` is not the generic term for all shells.

Comment: You can simplify the problem to `F=x echo $F`, which also does not output x. The shell parameter-expands the varibles in the  command **first**,  and **then** builds the environment for the execution (which includes setting the variable `F`), and then runs the command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're doing `F=$(basename "$FILE".fasta)`; that doesn't seem needed(?) Furthermore, the filename is already the full filename, so `"$FILE".fasta` should just be `$FILE`. That's why you're getting the "No such file: 'FILE.fasta.fasta'" error. It's always worked like this, so I'm not sure how that ever worked before.

Similarly, `"$F".input` will leave you with `filename.fasta.input`, which probably isn't what you want. You can remove the extension from a filename with `$varname:r` or `${varname:r}` ("r" as in "remove extension"). Note this will only work in zsh and not bash, in bash you'll have to use the much more awkward `${varname%.*}`.

You also don't need to use `ls` to iterate over files; it's intended for human displays, not programs.You can loop over files with just any glob pattern, which is much easier and less error-prone:

```
for FILE in *.fasta
```

---

Putting that together, you end up with something like:

```
for FILE in ./*.fasta; do
    COMMAND -f ${FILE:r}.input -o ${FILE:r}.output 
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. I got the script hand-me-down from an advisor, so I'll modify it using your suggestion. I'm a physical scientist who has recently had to transition to a more bioinformatics-heavy set of projects, so much of this is either second-hand scripts or self-taught. Thank you for your patience.